# Why array returns nil after appending to it elements?

Tags: ios, json, swift, model-view-controller, swifty-json

I'm trying to work with JSON as MVC model, for this I did:

```
// Country.swift
import SwiftyJSON

class Country {
     var code: String!
     var dialCode: Int!
     var name: String!

     init(json: JSON) {
          for i in 0...json["countries"].count - 1 {
             if let code = json["countries"][i]["code2"].string, dialCode = json["countries"][i]["dialCode"].string, name = json["countries"][i]["name"].string {
                 self.code = code
                 self.dialCode = Int(dialCode)
                 self.name = name
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

and later in my ViewController I do:

```
var countries = [Country]()

Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(property.host)\(property.getCountryList)", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
    do {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        countries.append(Country(json: json))
    } catch _ {

    }   
}
```

but I have a problem. When I print values in Country.swift file, I get results, but when I `print(countries)` it returns me `[Project.Country]` and count returns 1. What is the problem? What I do wrong?

Comment: try to print print(countries[0]);

Comment: @KishoreKumar the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood is this not your desired behaviour?

`countries` is an array of `Project.Country`, which swift is representing by printing `[Project.Country]` (an array containing one instance of your class). There is no issue.  If you want to prove that the array contains a `Project.Country` you should print one of the class' properties: `print(countries.first.name)`

EDIT: problem is you are passing a `JSON` array of countries to a single init method, which is just setting the properties of itself for every country and not creating an instance for each. Hence you only have one instance returned

Comment: yes, you are right. Also, I can use as `countries[0].name`, but it's not comfortable to use it. How can I get countries array count? When I try to print `countries.count` it returns me 1

Comment: I'm guessing you are expecting to return multiple countries through your request? In your `Project.Country` initialiser you are only creating one instance in your `for` loop, as you are setting the variables once for the same instance - not creating multiple!

Comment: Yes. There are 246 countries. So, I expect `246`

Comment: here `for i in 0...json["countries"].count - 1 {`? No, here it returns me `246`

Comment: You are using the `for` loop, yes, but only calling `init` once. You are passing `JSON` array of countries to a single `init`, which cycles through each country in the array and sets a single instance's properties to those values. So you are left with one `Country` instance which has had it's properties changed 246 times. You need to use the for loop outside the `init` and instead call `init` inside the `for` loop

Comment: @techbee Please don't do unnecessary edits. No need for bold when the text is already highlighted. And most of all, *do not add "Thanks" to any post*. You're supposed to *remove* the fluff with edits, not add it. Thank you.

Comment: I can only guess without seeing your updated code, but if it is returning `nil` then it will be `nil`. First ensure that `countries[0]` itself is not nil, and if not then check if the other properties (code and dialCode) are not nil so that we can narrow down where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are passing countries array to init method which is called only once you must do it like here

```
class Country {
    var code: String!
    var dialCode: Int!
    var name: String!

    init(json: JSON) {
            if let code = json["code2"].string, dialCode = json["dialCode"].string, name = json["name"].string {
                self.code = code
                self.dialCode = Int(dialCode)
                self.name = name
            }
    }
}
```

And loop here

```
  Alamofire.request(.POST, "", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in

                if let jsonResponse = response.result.value{
                    let json = JSON(jsonResponse)

                    for countriesJSON in json["countries"].arrayValue{
                        self.countries.append(Country(json: countriesJSON))
                    }

                    print(self.countries.count)
                }
            }
```